# Generate a tree from a flat array of objects where parent not specified by a key

Tags: javascript, arrays, tree

I have a flat array of objects which I am trying to generate a tree from.
The data originally is not sorted and is a product category data consumed from the API of an online marketplace which consists of around 5000 items.

A small part of data is as follows.

```
        "@deepest": "false",
        "categoryCode": "1",
        "categoryName": "Pet products"
    },
    {
        "@deepest": "false",
        "categoryCode": "1b",
        "categoryName": "Bird"
    },
    {
        "@deepest": "true",
        "categoryCode": "1ba",
        "categoryName": "Bird Accessories"
    },
    {
        "@deepest": "true",
        "categoryCode": "1bb",
        "categoryName": "Bird care products"
    },
    {
        "@deepest": "true",
        "categoryCode": "1bc",
        "categoryName": "Bird Cage"
    }
 ]
```

It appears that the trend within the data goes as categoryCode with single character being the top categories. 
Looking at the partial data, it can be seen that **categoryCode** **1** - which is *Pet Products* - has a child of with **categoryCode** **1b** and that of children **1bb** and **1bc** and so on.

So based on this relation, I am willing to generate a tree of objects as follows;

```
[
  {
    "@deepest": "false",
    "categoryCode": "1",
    "categoryName": "Pet products",
    "children": [
      {
        "@deepest": "false",
        "categoryCode": "1b",
        "categoryName": "Bird",
        "children": [
          {
            "@deepest": "true",
            "categoryCode": "1ba",
            "categoryName": "Bird Accessories"
          },
          {
            "@deepest": "true",
            "categoryCode": "1bb",
            "categoryName": "Bird care products"
          },
          {
            "@deepest": "true",
            "categoryCode": "1bc",
            "categoryName": "Bird Cage"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What would be the most optimal way to reach the desired output without having performance issues?

Note: Several attempts were made with no solid outcome but frustration.

Comment: in the wanted result, you have `1b` twice. is the category code reliable (haveing only one character for each nesting level)? where do you get the parent from?

Comment: I have thoroughly studies the data and it is indeed reliable. I must have made a typo, apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create this nested structure using `reduce` method and an object as a accumulator value where you could store both the value and the nested levels.

```js
const data = [{"@deepest":"false","categoryCode":"1","categoryName":"Pet products"},{"@deepest":"false","categoryCode":"1b","categoryName":"Bird"},{"@deepest":"true","categoryCode":"1ba","categoryName":"Bird Accessories"},{"@deepest":"true","categoryCode":"1bb","categoryName":"Bird care products Bakım Ürünleri"},{"@deepest":"true","categoryCode":"1bc","categoryName":"Bird Cage"}]

const { value: result } = data.reduce((a, o) => {
  return o.categoryCode.split('').reduce((r, e) => {
    if(!r[e]) {
      const obj = { ...o  }
      
      r[e] = { value: [] }
      
      if(o['@deepest'] !== 'true') {
       obj.children = r[e].value
      }
      
      r.value.push(obj)
    }
    
    return r[e]
  }, a), a
}, { value: [] })

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I would like ask, how does this actually work? What is the idea behind splitting the categoryCode of each element and reduce it to subs. I have been checking a lot of resources to find out reliable information about this. Could you please explain the implementation in pseudo? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For having strings which reflects their relation, you could collect all `categoryCode` and their objects and get the longes/closest relation and build a tree.

This approach works for longer codes than one character as well.

```js
var data = [{ "@deepest": "false", categoryCode: "1", categoryName: "Pet products" }, { "@deepest": "false", categoryCode: "1b", categoryName: "Bird" }, { "@deepest": "true", categoryCode: "1ba", categoryName: "Bird Accessories" }, { "@deepest": "true", categoryCode: "1bb", categoryName: "Bird care products Bakım Ürünleri" }, { "@deepest": "true", categoryCode: "1bc", categoryName: "Bird Cage" }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var t = { '': { children: [] } };
        array.forEach(o => t[o.categoryCode] = o);
        Object
            .keys(t)
            .sort((a, b) => a.length - b.length)
            .forEach((k, i, a) => {
                let j = i;
                while (j--) if (k.startsWith(a[j])) {
                    (t[a[j]].children = t[a[j]].children || []).push(t[k]);
                    break;
                };
            });
        return t[''].children;
    }(data, '');

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```